# How to create a personal branch in Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

I'm assisting in a project on Launchpad - however I do not have write access to that branch. How can I create a branch which I can push to and point people on the team for review?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Considering Launchpad is an integral part of the Ubuntu Ecosystem, and this site is about Ubuntu Users and Ubuntu *Developers* I would like to think this is ontopic. If you think otherwise feel free to open a top [on meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com) discussing why you feel Launchpad isn't ontopic to get feedback from the community.

Comment: That makes sense. I just thought it would be better on Web Applications SE. But, would you say Launchpad is the _canonical_ way to work on Ubuntu? [:P](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5fa0gQRAo1r6jaby.gif)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the project page that you want to create a branch for and click 'Submit Code'.

[image]

Then set up the branch. Make sure it is hosted in Launchpad.

[image]

You can then push to the branch:

```
bzr push lp:branch
```

The first time you push, you will need to use:

```
bzr push lp:branch --use-existing-dir
```

Once you are ready to merge, click 'Propose for merging' on the 'Code' tab of the project.

[image]

It will then wait to be reviewed by someone with the necessary permissions.

Once the review has started, you will see something like this in the 'Code' tab:
[image]

You can follow this link to the review page.
[image]

Once the reviewer is satisfied, they will merge the branches and your code will become part of the project's trunk.

Comment: Does that only work if the "Submit code" button is available or is it theoretically possible to request merge to personal branches created in the launchpad.net user profile page (when I request those for merge it fails with `This branch is not mergeable into lp:~[username]/+junk/[branch name]` after pushing a branch on commit ahead of master). Since the feedback doesn't give a reason and thus useless, I thought I ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can push a branch under your own name, e.g. `bzr push lp:~ajmitch/ubuntuwire-website/update-machine-list` to push a branch to the ubuntuwire-website project which is named update-machine-list

Answer (score 1):

Starting in the folder a level up from the branch:

```
bzr branch originalBranchName newBranchName
cd newBranchName
```

Make some changes to the files. If you add any new files/folders:

```
bzr add
```

Once you're done:

```
bzr commit -m "Description of changes"
```

And push to your own Launchpad branch:

```
bzr push lp:~lpusername/projectname/branchname
```

Answer (score 1):

For Subversion users, or those interested in lightweight checkouts, this might also help:

https://answers.launchpad.net/canonical-identity-provider/+question/209069

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...